# LINQ - query Where method error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, entity-framework, linq, runtime-error

I have the following code that I cannot make it work.

I am new using Linq and Entity framework.

I attach the code sample, and also, and image with the error.

What I am trying to do, is a piece of code where I can add "Where"s dynamically.

```
Imports System.Linq
Private cntx As New attmanager_bdEntities()

Dim query = (From persona In cntx.tblperson
                        Select
                        ATT_TYPE = persona.att_type,
                        ATT_RECOG = persona.att_recog,
                        APELLIDO = persona.surname,
                        NOMBRE = persona.name,
                        PERSONA_ID = persona.id,
                        DNI = persona.identification,
                        DIRECCION = persona.address,
                        PIN = persona.att_pin,
                        TIPOASISTENCIA = persona.att_type,
                        EMAIL = persona.email,
                        EXTRA = persona.extra,
                        TELEFONO = persona.phone,
                        FECHANACIMIENTO = persona.birth,
                        SEXO = persona.sex,
                        DELETED = persona.deleted,
                        AREA_ID = persona.tblarea.id,
                        AREA = persona.tblarea.name,
                        CIUDAD = persona.tblcity.name,
                        CIUDAD_ID = persona.tblcity_id,
                        PROVINCIA = persona.tblcity.tblstate.name,
                        PAIS = persona.tblcity.tblstate.tblcountry.name
                        Where (DELETED = 0))

        query = query.Where(Function(a) a.AREA_ID = 1)

'Here I should put another "Where"s
dbgrid_listado.DataSource = query.ToList()
```

[image]

Error translation:

> Unexpected exception trying to load "personas"
>   Details:
>   Could not invoke the method because could not call a 'Public Function Where ..........
>   ......
>   ......
>   ......
>   ...... with those arguments.
>   The parameter 'predicate' of the argument could not be converted to VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of Object,Object)' into 'String'

Comment: Can you translate the error In English and post it here?

Comment: You could have just edited the first version.

Comment: Honestly, what I can appretiate about this error occurs when I try to execute the following code:

query = query.Where(Function(a) a.AREA_ID = 1)

Seams that the Where method cannot be called with the Arguments I am giving to it.

Comment: I am totally lost. I am debuging another programmer software.

Comment: @fachamix - Please translate the error into English.

Comment: Already translated. Could be possible that the Entity version used, is not updated?

Comment: I'm just curious why you're selecting a new anonymous type instead of just selecting a new persona... are there properties you don't want to bring back?

Comment: @BarryFranklin , how would that be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it ....

I created a new project

I migrate all the resources (images for example) from the old project to this new one.

Opened the NuGet package manager, and installed EF6
Also installed MySQL.Data and MySQL EF6 provider.

I imported the forms, from the original project to the new one.

Now I can do what you guys suggested.

The Problem ??? .... The version on .Net framework, and the EF I was using.

I had t update everything.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
Dim query = (From persona In cntx.tblperson
             Where persona.DELETED = 0
             Select persona)
```

Now your type is "persona" instead of an anonymous type of 21 random properties.

```
query = query.Where(Function(a) a.AREA_ID = 1)
```

Working with anonymous types is always tricky. Also, I always put the select last...

You could always list out the properties in an anonymous type like this:

```
Dim query = (From persona In cntx.tblperson
            Where persona.DELETED = 0
            Select New With {
                        ATT_TYPE = persona.att_type,
                        ATT_RECOG = persona.att_recog,
                        APELLIDO = persona.surname,
                        NOMBRE = persona.name,
                        PERSONA_ID = persona.id,
                        DNI = persona.identification,
                        DIRECCION = persona.address,
                        PIN = persona.att_pin,
                        TIPOASISTENCIA = persona.att_type,
                        EMAIL = persona.email,
                        EXTRA = persona.extra,
                        TELEFONO = persona.phone,
                        FECHANACIMIENTO = persona.birth,
                        SEXO = persona.sex,
                        DELETED = persona.deleted,
                        AREA_ID = persona.tblarea.id,
                        AREA = persona.tblarea.name,
                        CIUDAD = persona.tblcity.name,
                        CIUDAD_ID = persona.tblcity_id,
                        PROVINCIA = persona.tblcity.tblstate.name,
                        PAIS = persona.tblcity.tblstate.tblcountry.name
                        })
```

Maybe the where clause using the anon type is messing it up and using `persona.DELETED = 0` would help?

Comment: I get the following error with the new query.
> The public member 'Where' of type DbQuery(Of tblperson)

Comment: This is driving me crazy

Comment: If you're using an older version of vb.net (visual studio 2008 for example), you may need to add underscores after each line in the query like "From persona In cntx.tblperson _" - except the last line.

Comment: using visual studio 2013

Comment: I am installing entity framework 6 now (using 5 at the examples), also the db is MySQL

Comment: You should need underscores then... I think they aren't needed as of 2015